# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. SQL MERGE

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I am trying to follow the example here but something is wrong with my temp table. please help?
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Create my Sproc

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  gssenv.InsertMorphoDevice  
    @Name nvarchar(MAX),  
    @Description nvarchar(MAX),  
    @Location nvarchar(MAX),  
    @AssetID nvarchar(MAX),  
    @TimeZone nvarchar(MAX), 
    @Hostname nvarchar(50), 
    @Port int,   
    @Status int, 
    @ID nvarchar(50)
AS   
BEGIN  
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  

    MERGE gssenv.Morpho  AS target  
    USING (SELECT @ID,@Name,@Description,@Location,@AssetID,@TimeZone,@Hostname,@Port,@Status) AS source (ID,Name,Description,Location,AssetID,TimeZone,Hostname,Port,Status)  
    ON (target.ID = source.ID)  
    WHEN MATCHED THEN   
        UPDATE 
        SET Hostname = source.Hostname,
            Name =     source.Name,
            Description = source.Description,
            Location = source.Location,
            AssetID = source.AssetID ,
            Port = source.Port,
            Status = source.Status,
            ID = source.ID

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  
    INSERT (ID,Name,Description,Location,AssetID,TimeZone,Hostname,Port,Status)  
    VALUES (source.ID,source.Name,source.Description,source.Location,source.AssetID,source.TimeZone,source.Hostname,source.Port,source.Status)
    OUTPUT deleted.*, $action, inserted.* INTO #MyTempTable;  
END;  
GO
```

-- Create a temptable for OUTPUT

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTempTable  
    (ExistingDescription nvarchar(MAX),
     ExistingName nvarchar(MAX),  
     ExistingLocation nvarchar(MAX),  
     ExistingAssetID nvarchar(MAX), 
     ExistingHostname nvarchar(MAX), 
     ExistingTimeZone nvarchar(MAX), 
     [ExistingID] nvarchar(MAX), 
     ExistingPort int, 
     ExistingStatus int, 
    ExistingDate datetime,  
    ActionTaken nvarchar(10),  
     NewDescription nvarchar(MAX), 
     NewName nvarchar(MAX),  
     NewLocation nvarchar(MAX),  
     NewAssetID nvarchar(MAX), 
     NewHostname nvarchar(MAX), 
     NewTimeZone nvarchar(MAX), 
     [NewID] nvarchar(MAX), 
     NewPort int, 
     NewStatus int, 
     NewDate datetime  
    );  
GO
```

-- Test the procedure and return the results.

```
EXEC gssenv.InsertMorphoDevice  @Name = 'ABC', @Description = 'Name',@Location = 'test',@AssetID= 'NEWASSSETID', @Hostname = 'MPK40-PSEC-BIO-0024AE01B5C5.thefacebook.com',
                         @Port = '1234',@Status =2,@TimeZone = 'tzsdf', @ID = '2E4F5071-EAD7-4E22-8AB7-36AB20C2A33A'
```

Error message:

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Procedure InsertMorphoDevice, Line 15 [Batch Start Line 74]
    Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Comment: The problem is with this: `OUTPUT deleted.*, $action, inserted.* INTO #MyTempTable;` Your `OUTPUT` does not match the definition of `#MyTempTable`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what looks to be happening. Your `OUTPUT` does not match the definition of the table that you are inserting into (`#MyTempTable`):

[image]

The `$action` value is what is triggering the error, but it is all incorrect.

You need to either (a) change the definition of `#MyTempTable` or (b) correct your `OUTPUT` by adding in the missing values (the dates).